# When a 2nd Wordpress blog is added to Azure, it doesn't work

Tags: wordpress, azure

I tried to add a second wordpress website to my Azure environment. They both have their own subdomain. But when I tried to launch the new site for the first time, it didn't work. A blank page comes up instead of the expected Admin Configuration that normally runs on initial startup.

Answer (score 0):

You need to manually edit the $table_prefix in wp-config.php and change it. What you change it to doesn't really matter. The problem, it turns out, is that both of the instances point to the same default wp_ prefix, so the second instance is getting confused. Once you change it, when you go to the site, you will see the correct answer.

Kudos to John White. This is his answer, which I discovered here: http://whitepages.unlimitedviz.com/2014/01/using-multiple-wordpress-blogs-with-azure-web-sites/